# check if checkbox is checked add value else if unchecked remove value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have checkbox html.

```
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>Air Conditioning</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>Cable TV Service</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>Private Bathroom</span></label>
```

I need to have seperate value for each checkbox, so I can get those values from all and store in variable. For example

```
<label><input type="checkbox" data="1"><span>Air Conditioning</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data="2"><span>Cable TV Service</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data="3"><span>Private Bathroom</span></label>
```

So if all the 3 are selected I will need my variable as

```
room_features = '1-2-3';
```

If any one is then unchecked, variable will be updated as

```
room_features = '2-3';
```

So on every change on checkbox, variable should be updated. I am confused if either adding data="1" etc is fine for checkboxes? I normally do for anchors when there is single double quotes.

Comment: Why don't you use `value="1"` ? And where is your javascript ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290772/check-if-checkbox-is-checked-add-value-else-if-unchecked-remove-value/19291102#19291102

Answer (score 2):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sZQtL/40/)**

You should use **value** in each checkbox. for ex:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" checked />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />
```

**JQuery:**

```
var searchIDs = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data="1"><span>Air Conditioning</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data="2"><span>Cable TV Service</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" data="3"><span>Private Bathroom</span></label>
```

**JS**

```
 var selectedvalue=[];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){

    selectedvalue.push($(this).attr("data"));

    });

alert(selectedvalue.join("-"));// your desired result
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/LArBW/21/)**

reference **[Arrays](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/arrays/)** and **[checked-selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` method, note that I have added `value` attribute to the element instead of `data` as an input should have a value otherwise what's the point of using it? If you want to use `data-*` attributes, you should specify an identifier. Something like  `<input type="checkbox" data-id="1">`, then you can get the value using jQuery `data()` method: `$(elem).data('id');`.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Air Conditioning</span></label>
...
```

```
var vals = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
     return this.value; // return $(this).data('whatever');
}).get().join('-');
```

`get()` returns an array, if you need an array you can remove the `.join()` method which returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

javascript

```
getElementById("chkbox1").checked=true;
```

jquery

```
$("#chkbox1").prop("checked");
```

or

```
$("#chkbox1").attr("checked");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this dynamic one

```
var room_features = "";

$('[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
var data = "-" + $(this).attr('data');
if (room_features.indexOf(data) != -1) {
    room_features = room_features.replace(data, "");
    alert(room_features);
} else {
    room_features = room_features + data;
    alert(room_features);
}
});
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/nqNfe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LpSsN/)

```
$("#btn").click(function(event){
    var selectedvalue=[];
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){

selectedvalue.push($(this).attr("data"));

});

alert(selectedvalue.join("-"));// your desired result

  })
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and @Riturajratan's answer? You  just add a click handler, even variables are the same.

Comment: with this button you can check any time